# Custom file owner of a nib file leaks in OS X / Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I need my class, call it `Document`, to be the file owner of a nib containing the user interface (just as `Document: NSDocument` is the file owner in the Apple's document-based template). Likewise, I do not want `Document` to inherit from `NSWindowController`, but to manage an instance of it that will load the nib and set its `Document` as the file owner:

```
let windowController = NSWindowController(windowNibName: "DocumentWindow", owner: self)
```

Sounds simple, yet I am unable to get the file owner to deallocate along with all the other nib objects. The reason for this is that, according to Apple, "**For historical reasons, in OS X the top-level objects in a nib file are created with an additional reference count.**" (see: [Top-level Objects in OS X May Need Special Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6))

If I set the window's `isReleasedWhenClosed` to `true` and set the property itself to `nil`, then its `deinit` is called. Similarly with the instance of the `NSWindowController`... but the instance of `Document`, the file owner, remains! It's `deinit` is never called.

If I set the file owner to be the window controller, everything deallocates fine, including the `Document` instance, but this setup is difficult to subclass, which is what I need... I need the `Document` instance to be the file owner.

And so, for my case, the documentation suggests the following:

> *If the File’s Owner is not an instance of `NSWindowController` or
>   `NSViewController`*, then you need to decrement the reference count of
>   the top level objects yourself. You must cast references to top-level
>   objects to a Core Foundation type and use `CFRelease`.

But how can I do this in Swift?

Would be grateful for any insight and suggestions!